# how to select values from a list within a Range using while and if loop?

Tags: r, while-loop

I have a list with values and I need to select values from this list that are greater or equal to 3 and less than/equal to 4 but I don't know how to do so using the while and if loops. Anyone could give me a clue on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood what you have in mind correctly, you can use the following solution. Imagine we have a vector of length 20 called `vec`:

- We first create an empty vector `out` to store our result in it during in every iteration (if any)
- Then we set the iterator `i` to its first value (here we set the initial value to 1)

While loops begin by testing a condition (i <= length(vec)), so after that they execute the body (our if clause and subsequent assigning of value that meets our requirements(>=3 & <=4) to `out`). It then adds one to the iterator and evaluates the condition again and so forth.

```
vec <- sample(1:10, size = 20, replace = TRUE)

out <- c()
i <- 1

while(i <= length(vec)) {
  if(vec[i] <= 4 & vec[i] >= 3) {
    out <- c(out, vec[i])
  } 
  i <- i + 1
}
out

[1] 4 3
```

Comment: I'm a total beginner at R so sorry if my question was a bit confusing but I tried your solution without the sample part and it worked perfectly for my purpose. Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh my pleasure, you don't have to be sorry for asking questions, we all have been there.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't need any `while/if` statements, you can simply apply

```
x[x >= 3 & x <= 4]
```

---

If you have to use `while` and `if` to make it, below is one option

```
k <- 1
res <- c()
while(k < length(x)) {
    if (x[k] >= 3 & x[k] <= 4) {
        res <- append(res,x[k])
    }
    k <- k + 1
}
```